# Upload de Pasta com Angular (não apenas múltiplos arquivos, mas do diretório todo)

Tags: angular, multiple-file-upload

Estou usando o ngx-admin com Nebular para um projeto de Dashboard.

O meu código a seguir funciona bem para enviar múltiplos arquivos. Contudo ocorre um erro quando se tenta enviar uma pasta (arrastando a pasta para o input de arquivos)

O que preciso alterar para que seja possível o envio de um diretório?

***template-sent.component.html***

```
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event.target.files)" multiple="multiple">

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="progress + '%'">{{progress}}%</div>
</div>
```

***template-sent.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpEventType
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from "environments/environment";

@Component({
    selector: "template-sent",
    templateUrl: "./template-sent.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./template-sent.component.scss"]
})
export class TemplateSentComponent {
    progress: number;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    upload(file) {
        this.progress = 1;
        const formData = new FormData();

        for (const index in file) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(file, index)) {
                formData.append("files[]", file[index]);
            }
        }

        this.http
            .post(environment.sentTemplateEmail, formData, {
                reportProgress: true,
                observe: "events"
            })
            .pipe(
                map((event: any) => {
                    if (event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                        this.progress = Math.round((100 / event.total) * event.loaded);
                    } else if (event.type == HttpEventType.Response) {
                        this.progress = 100;
                        console.log(event.body);
                    }
                }),
                catchError((err: any) => {
                    this.progress = null;
                    alert(err.message);
                    return throwError(err.message);
                })
            )
            .toPromise();
    }
}
```

---

Veja um exemplo da ideia que quero aplicar (só que com um diretório inteiro, e não apenas com arquivos individuais ou múltiplos arquivos)

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue solução para aqueles que tenham a mesma dificuldade:

No HTML basta usar o atributo `webkitDirectory` para permitir o envio de uma pasta. Isso por si só já irá resolver o problema, fazendo com que o script leia cada arquivo dentro da pasta enviada, recursivamente.

***template-sent.component.html***

```
<input #folderInput type="file" (change)="upload($event.target.files)" multiple="multiple" webkitDirectory>
```

Porém, para o envio dos paths é necessário usar a propriedade `webkitRelativePath` de cada arquivo, dessa forma:

***template-sent.component.ts***

```
...
upload(file) {
        this.progress = 1;
        const formData = new FormData();

        for (const index in file) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(file, index)) {
                // Pega o arquivo atual
                const thisFile = file[index];
                // Grava os dados dele para envio
                formData.append('files[]', thisFile);
                // Garava o path original dele
                formData.append('paths[]', thisFile.webkitRelativePath);
            }
        }
        ...
```

O resultado desse envio para o back-end serão 2 campos do tipo array, `files` e `paths`, o primeiro contendo os dados dos arquivos enviados e o segundo contendo o caminho completo de cada arquivo, algo semelhante a isso:

```
files:
    error: Array(3) 
        [0, 0, 0]
    name: Array(3) 
        ["imagem1.jpg", "imagem2.jpg", "documento1.docx"]
    size: Array(3) 
        [179686, 179686, 0]
    tmp_name: Array(3) 
        ["D:\xampp\tmp\php289A.tmp", "D:\xampp\tmp\php28AB.tmp", "D:\xampp\tmp\php28AC.tmp"]
    type: Array(3) 
        ["image/jpeg", "image/jpeg", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"]

paths: Array(3)
    0: "pasta-exemplo/imagem1.jpg"
    1: "pasta-exemplo/imagem2.jpg"
    2: "pasta-exemplo/sub-pasta/documento1.docx"
```

**Resultado**
[image: Resultado]

*Fonte:* https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2018/01/03/folder-upload-in-an-angular-app/

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigada, eu estava precisando disso também